# Flutter - how to make Page scrollable if content Overflows, but Expanded if it doesnt?

Tags: flutter, layout

I'm trying to achieve a specific layout but I cannot wrap my head on why it doesnt work.

I have  a layout where the center body MUST be expanded, because even if the content is too little to fill the space, I want that the red boxes and buttons are **always** at the bottom:

[image]

In the first image, all is good, if the text is short.

Now if we have a huge text, what I actually want, is that the whole page becomes scrollable, and the red boxes and buttons will be placed AFTER the text (keeping all the spacing given by my SizedBoxes).

What happens instead is, my text in the center gets cut.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that my desider layout is basically what Google's Gmail app for mobile does, basically if the email is short, the Answer+Forward button will stay at the bottom, but if the email is long and scrollable, the buttons will be at the end of the text

My code:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final availableHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - kToolbarHeight - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;


    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 16, 24, 16),
              height: availableHeight,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 12,),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          "title",
                        )
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text("after title"),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 32,),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 45,
                        height: 45,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                Flexible(
                                  child: Text("Name LastName"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 12,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Date"
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text("subtitle")
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 50,
                                ),
                                Icon(Icons.star)
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(_lorem),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    height: 40,
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                  ),
                  Wrap(
                    spacing: 20,
                    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      TextButton(onPressed: () => Null, child: Text("press me")),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 30
                      ),
                      TextButton(onPressed: () => Null, child: Text("press me")),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

I'm not sure how to make this page Scrollable if the content is bigger than the height, keeping
all widgets original sizes, but if the body content is short, then just display the body text and keep the buttons at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/scrolling here are some scrollable widgets that might help.

If you want the thing at the bottom to always be at the bottom of the text, one solution would be to put the text and all the stuff at the bottom into a ListView.

something like:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ...
    ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        Text(_lorem),
        Divider(
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.grey[400],
        ),
        ...
      ],
    )
    ...
  ],
)
```

If you're new to scrollable widgets though, you should definitely look into it because there are plenty of other alternatives that might suit this case better.

Comment: I tested most of the scrolling containers to achieve what I'm looking for, and the combo SingleChildScrollView+Column with in the middle a Container with viewport size comes actually from a SO answer on how to use SingleChildScrollView + Column. Your answer is pointless, give some real examples please

Comment: your proposed solution cannot work. The buttons MUST be at the bottom of the screen if the Text(_lorem) text is short. By just slapping everything into a ListView, if the _lorem is just 1 line, the buttons will be at the top of the page...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code

```
class View extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final availableHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        kToolbarHeight -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(''),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 16, 24, 16),
            height: availableHeight,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 12,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                      "title",
                    )),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("after title"),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 32,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 45,
                      height: 45,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 15,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Flexible(
                                child: Text("Name LastName"),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 12,
                              ),
                              Text("Date"),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(child: Text("subtitle")),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 50,
                              ),
                              Icon(Icons.star)
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                            "LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. In ante metus dictum at. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod. In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis. Non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis. Quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi.At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. Cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed. Ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque. In cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti. Massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc. Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies.Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate. Blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim. Lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus. Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum. In eu mi bibendum neque egestas. Sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. In cursus turpis massa tincidunt. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Quis commodo odio aenean sed. Molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a. Aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor commodo.Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan. In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non. Interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio. Mauris a diam maecenas sed. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque. Etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum. Ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in.Leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. At quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim. Placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis. Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. Id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas."),
                        Divider(
                          height: 40,
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                        ),
                        Wrap(
                          spacing: 20,
                          crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: 100,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: 100,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: 100,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 40,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () => Null, child: Text("press me")),
                            SizedBox(width: 30),
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () => Null, child: Text("press me")),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

or you can try this as well

```
class CompletePageScroll extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final availableHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        kToolbarHeight -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(''),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 16, 24, 16),
              height: availableHeight,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                        "title",
                      )),
                      Container(
                        child: Text("after title"),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 32,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 45,
                        height: 45,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                Flexible(
                                  child: Text("Name LastName"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 12,
                                ),
                                Text("Date"),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(child: Text("subtitle")),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 50,
                                ),
                                Icon(Icons.star)
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                              "LLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. In ante metus dictum at. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod. In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis. Non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis. Quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi.At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. Cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed. Ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque. In cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti. Massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc. Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies.Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate. Blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim. Lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus. Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum. In eu mi bibendum neque egestas. Sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. In cursus turpis massa tincidunt. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Quis commodo odio aenean sed. Molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a. Aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor commodo.Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan. In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non. Interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio. Mauris a diam maecenas sed. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque. Etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum. Ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in.Leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. At quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim. Placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis. Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. Id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas."),
                          Divider(
                            height: 40,
                            color: Colors.grey[400],
                          ),
                          Wrap(
                            spacing: 20,
                            crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 100,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 100,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 100,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 40,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () => Null,
                                  child: Text("press me")),
                              SizedBox(width: 30),
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () => Null,
                                  child: Text("press me")),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: neither of these solutions is correct. It only fixes the "easy" part, to make the text scrollable and place the buttons after it. The main issue is, if the _lorem is SHORT, so in your example, try to change the Text("LLorem ...) to something much shorter, and you will see that the buttons now are NOT at the bottom of the screen but just after the text. I need that when the text is short, the buttons at the bottom will be at the end of the screen (that is why I wrapped the body text in an expanded(), to make it fill all the space even if the text is short, but it doesnt work)

Comment: OK I will check with it.